# How to find out which word matched?

Tags: python, regex, findall

I've a pattern to find some words etc in a string. Here is my code:

```
    pattern = {
        "eval\(.*\)",
        "hello",
        "my word"
    }

    patterns = "|" . join( pattern )
    patterns = "(^.*?(" + patterns + ").*?$)"

    code = code.strip()

    m = re.findall( patterns, code, re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE|re.UNICODE )

    if m:
        return m
```

How can i see which of these words (eval(), hello ..) was found? In php i have the function preg_match_all to get the matched word that was found.

Comment: nope. when its so easy, i dont have to ask for it. I need two informations, something like this:

"hello", (the word that matched)
"hello my friend" (the whole line with the matching word)

Comment: You should really update your question to specifically ask about the second piece of info.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it's what you intended, but your regexp has two levels of capturing groups:

```
    (^.*?(hello|my word|eval\(.*\)).*?$)
```

The outer group will capture the whole line, whereas the inner group will only capture the specified words.

The `re.findall` method returns a list of tuples containing the captured groups. In your particular case, this will be:

```
    [(outer_group, inner_group), (outer_group, inner_group), ...]
```

To iterate over this, you could do:

```
    for line, words in m:
        print('line:', line)
        print('words:', words)
```

or to just access the items directly, do this:

```
    line = m[0][0]
    words = m[0][1]
```

NB:

If the outer group is removed, or made non-capturing, like this:

```
    ^.*?(hello|my word|eval\(.*\)).*?$
```

or this

```
    (?:^.*?(hello|my word|eval\(.*\)).*?$)
```

there would only be one capturing group. For this specific case, `re.findall` will return a flat list of the matches (i.e. just single strings, not tuples).

Answer (score 0):

```
pattern = {
    "eval\(.*\)",
    "hello",
    "my word"
}
patterns = "|" . join( pattern )
patterns = "^.*?(" + patterns + ").*?$"

code = "i say hello to u"

m = re.match( patterns, code, re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE|re.UNICODE )

if m:
    print m.group()  #the line that matched
    print m.group(1) #the word that matched
```

What you need `match` instead of `findall`.

`match.group` will give you the whole line matched and `match.group(1)` or `match.group(2)` in your case will give you the word.